# i am getting an error while using azure stprage blob sdk while undeleting a container which is deleted

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-python-sdk

i am  getting an error while using azure stprage blob sdk while undeleting a container which is deleted.

These are the package versions i am using:

azure-storage-blob = "=12.18.3"
azure-mgmt-storage = "=21.1.0"

i have created the blobserviceclient and calling undelete_container function to recover a deleted container.

## Create the BlobServiceClient object

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(storage_account_url, credential=default_credential)
recovered_containers = blob_service_client.undelete_container(container_name, deleted_container_version = '')
```

the issue i am facing is "deleted_container_version" is a mandatory parameter for undelete_container. but i dont know what is the value to be provided. This is defined as a string parameter.

What should be the value i neeed to pass?

this is the properties i see on deleted container.
[image]

please guide me in fixing this. Thank you in advance

i did tried with deleted_container_version as an empty string, latest values, without passing.

while not passing deleted_container_version getting an error stating deleted_container_version is a mandatory parameter and needs to be passed.

while passing them as empty string or latest, getting an error stating the header version was an invalid value or something like that,

Comment: I think you need to list all container include the deleted ones too, after it you can get the version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-containers-list-python

Comment: this helped me resolve the issue.

blob_service_client = create_blob_service_client(storage_account=storage_account)
    container_list = list(blob_service_client.list_containers(include_deleted=True))
    assert len(container_list) >= 1
    for container in container_list:
        # Find the deleted container and restore it
        if container.deleted and container.name == container_name:
            restored_container_client = blob_service_client.undelete_container(
                deleted_container_name=container.name, deleted_container_version=container.version)

Comment: @Krishnadhas Check the below answer also.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an error while using Azure storage blob sdk while undeleting a container that is deleted.

I agree with KKI's comment to get the deleted containers first list the container with **`include_deleted=True`** from that you can get the version of your container.

To **`undelete`** particular container **`test`** from Azure blob storage you can use the below Python code.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

storage_account_url="https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/"
default_credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(storage_account_url, credential=default_credential)

for container in blob_service_client.list_containers(include_metadata=True, include_deleted=True):
    if container.name == "<container name>":
        version_id = container.version
        break


blob_service_client.undelete_container("test", deleted_container_version=version_id)
```

**Output:**
[image]

If you need to **`undelete all`** container you can use the below code.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

storage_account_url="https://venkat901.blob.core.windows.net/"
default_credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(storage_account_url, credential=default_credential)

for container in blob_service_client.list_containers(include_metadata=True, include_deleted=True):
    if container.deleted:
        version_id = container.version
        container_name = container.name
        
        blob_service_client.undelete_container(container_name, deleted_container_version=version_id)
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[List blob containers with Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-containers-list-python#include-deleted-containers)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works.

```
def recover_soft_deleted_containers_on_storage_account(storage_account: str, container_name: str):
    """
    recover soft deleted containers.
    Operation will only be successful if used within the specified number of days set in the delete retention policy.

    Args:
        storage_account:
        container_name:

    Returns:

    """
    blob_service_client = create_blob_service_client(storage_account=storage_account)
    container_list = list(blob_service_client.list_containers(include_deleted=True))
    assert len(container_list) >= 1
    for container in container_list:
        # Find the deleted container and restore it
        if container.deleted and container.name == container_name:
            restored_container_client = blob_service_client.undelete_container(
                deleted_container_name=container.name, deleted_container_version=container.version)
    print(f"Container {container_name} recovered from {storage_account}")
```